# Set style for uneditable textinput and textarea flex components

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, textarea, textinput

Is there a way to change the style (background color) for all textinput and textarea components in a flex program with the 'editable' property set to false?

Thanks

Comment: Please specify: Flex 3 or 4?

Answer (score 2):

### Create a custom skin

Since there is no specific style for this, you'll have to create a custom skin. Just follow these steps:

- Create a custom skin for TextInput. First create a new mxml file (for instance called MyTextInputSkin.mxml). The easiest approach now is to simply copy all of the code from `spark.skins.spark.TextInputSkin` into your new class.
- Override the `updateDisplayList()` method and apply the necessary changes to the skin's classes based on the host component's `editable` property. For instance:

.

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(
    unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {

    super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
    //when editable the background will be red and otherwise it'll be blue
    background.color = hostComponent.editable ? 0xff0000 : 0x0000ff;
}
```

- Apply this skin to all TextInputs through a CSS selector, like this:

.

```
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";

s|TextInput {
    skinClass: ClassReference("my.skins.MyTextInputSkin");
}
```

- Repeat for the TextArea component

---

### Make it more generic

You can make it more generic by doing somethin like the following.
In the updateDisplayList() method:

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(
    unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {

    super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

    var bgColorStyle:String = "backgroundColor";
    if (!hostComponent.editable) = "nonEditableBackgroundColor";
    background.color = getStyle(bgColorStyle);
}
```

And in CSS:

```
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";

s|TextInput {
    skinClass: ClassReference("my.skins.MyTextInputSkin");
    backGroundColor: #ff0000;
    nonEditableBackgroundColor: #0000ff;
}
```

This way you can reuse the custom skin everywhere and apply differnt colors through styling.
Note that you will not be able to set `nonEditableBackgroundColor` through MXML because the host component doesn't have that style declared in its metadata. This does not apply to `backGroundColor` because it is a default style and is declared in TextInput's  metadata.

Comment: The problem is, the textinputs and areas are all mx components.  Can I skin those?

Comment: Nope, not like this anyway. That's why I asked whether your question was about Flex 3 or 4. You really should be more specific in your questions.